# Adding digital product in ACEShop Joomla Component

Tags: joomla2.5, aceshop

I was trying to use Joomla 2.5 ACEShop component to sell my digital goods. But unfortunately i could not able to find the right option to add my digital products. I was using free version of it and not sure if i can use it to get my task done. Can anyone reply is that was a possible on with ACEShop free component ?

I could see some options under "Option" tab but unfortunately it was not working as expected. Am not sure it is because i use free version or it does the same on paid version too.

Answer (score 0):

you may find this helpful. It refers to Opencart, but since AceShop is still based on the Opencart software as its core, the same directions should apply.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/303-creating-a-downloadable-product-in-opencart

Comment: Thanks for reply sir... i have choose to go with magento as i need to customize more options on digital products download. The ACEShop does not seems to be the right one for me. Thanks a lot for reply :)